# Slot number cannot be filled

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I got a strange message with the derivative of a two-argument function defined by a definite integral. For example if "f" is defined as:

```
f[r_, z_] := Integrate[k*a[k*r]*b[k*z], {k, 0, km}]
Derivative[1, 0][f][0, 0]
```

I get a message, that I don't understand, before the correct result:

> Function::slotn : Slot number 2 in `!FreeQ[k a[k #1] b[k #2],#1]&` cannot be filled from `(!FreeQ[k a[k #1] b[k #2],#1]&)[If]`
>       (*... Several more similar Function::slotn messages ...*)

```
(*1/3 km^3 b[0] Derivative[1][a][0]*)
```

Is something incorrect?

Comment: Note that the answer returned by Mathematica is still correct (you get the same result if you use `D[f[r, z], r] /. {r -> 0, z -> 0}`), but I agree that the error message is still strange.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert. Is that expression actually correct? It looks like it's replacing the values in the integrand, at which point it sees `a[0]` and `b[0]` as constants, so it pulls them out of the integral and just does the integration over `k`. But this is the incorrect order. You have to do the integration *first*, *then* plug in 0 for `r` and `z`. Maybe I'm not thinking about this correctly, and the integration by parts makes it work...

Comment: No. I'm not crazy. Try this: `f[r_] = Integrate[k a[k*r](**b[k*z]*), {k, 0, km}]`, then `D[f[r], r] /. r -> 0 /. a -> ((# + 1)^2/k &)` and `D[f[r], r] /. a -> ((# + 1)^2/k &) /. r -> 0`.

Comment: @march: I think the only reason you're not getting the same answer there is because you're using a function for `a` that depends on `k` independently from the combination `kr` (i.e., $\partial a(x) /\partial k \neq 0$ when $x$ is held constant.)  If you use a true function of a single variable, I'm fairly certain the results are correct.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert. Yes, you're right. I was trying my hardest to break the problem and didn't notice that I was doing something silly. Thanks.

Comment: @JeanFABRE, notice that no problem for `g[r_, z_] := Integrate[k*a[t*r]*b[t*z], {k, 0, km}]` or `h[r_, z_] := Integrate[k*a[k*r]*b[k*z], k]`. Looks like a bug...

Comment: A few clarifications: 1) the problem is the MESSAGE and not the result which is always correct, 2) functions `a[k*r]` and `b[k*z]` are pure function already defined (in fact Bessel and/or Hankel functions), 3) it is true that no message is displayed for indefinite integral and a fortiori when `a` and `b` are independent of `k`, 4) strangely, I get no message when using the partial derivative symbol of the Typesetting Palette (Writing Assistant)  !!! Sorry but I don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug due to the use of slots (`#1`, `#2`, ...) internally in the implementations of `Derivative` and of `Integrate`.

**Focus first on Derivative.**  `Derivative[1,0][Print]` prints `#1#2`.  This means that at least one branch of the code for `Derivative` involves calling `Print[#1,#2]`.  In your case, `Derivative[1,0][f]` calls `f[#1,#2]`.

**Focus next on Integrate** The simple example `Integrate[b[k, #2], {k, 0, 1}]` leads to many messages of the form

> Function::slotn: Slot number 2 in !FreeQ[b[k,#2],#1]& cannot be filled from (!FreeQ[b[k,#2],#1]&)[If].
>
> Function::slotn: Slot number 2 in !FreeQ[b[k,#2],#1]& cannot be filled from (!FreeQ[b[k,#2],#1]&)[Which].
>
> Function::slotn: Slot number 2 in !FreeQ[b[k,#2],#1]& cannot be filled from (!FreeQ[b[k,#2],#1]&)[Abs].

this means that somewhere in the (non-public) implementation of `Integrate`, there are tests of whether the expression to integrate contains `If`, `Which`, `Abs`, etc (to see the whole list do `Off[General::stop]` and look at the last word in each message).  These tests are probably written as `(!FreeQ[`*`expr`*`,#1]&)[If]`, where *`expr`* stands for the expression to integrate (and not for a variable evaluating to it).

Here, I took `b[k, #2]`, which means that *Mathematica* sees the test as `(!FreeQ[b[k,#2],#1]&)[If]`, which cannot be evaluated because `#2` requires the anonymous function `(...&)` to be called with at least 2 arguments.

**Why does this come up in your case?**

`Derivative[1, 0][f]` calls `f[#1,#2]`, which evaluates to `Integrate` with `#1` and `#2` in its argument, which leads to the messages described above.  This would not come up in some simpler cases where `Integrate` can (more easily) perform the integral (e.g., if `b[k*z]` is replaced by `b[z]` as that is a constant), or where the second variable `z` (or rather, `#2`) does not appear.

I advise you not to trust the results even when there are no messages: the tests `!FreeQ[`*`expr`*`,#1]&[If]` will evaluate to `True` if the *`expr`* contains `#1` even though they are meant for testing the presence of `If`.  This means that *Mathematica*'s integration routine will operate under the assumption that the expression contains an `If` (and also a `While`, `Abs`, etc.).  This may simply cause *Mathematica* to be more careful, but it could lead to incorrect results.

**A workaround**: One very ugly way to get `Derivative` to work with a function `f` which involves `Integrate` is to catch the case where `f` receives slots as arguments:

```
f[#1, #2] := 
  Module[{r, z}, Unevaluated @@ {f[r, z]} /. {r -> #1, z -> #2}];
f[r_, z_] := Integrate[k*a[k*r] b[k*z], {k, 0, km}];
Unevaluated' := 1 &;
```

However, I'm not sure I trust this code: `Derivative[1, 0][f]` involves the derivative of `Unevaluated`, which I had to define as being a constant function with value `1`: then `Unevaluated'` disappears when evaluating particular values of `Derivative[1, 0][f][0, 0]`.

A safer approach probably is to use `D` explicitly with named variables and replacement rules to evaluate: for instance, `D[f[r,z],r]/.{r:>0,z:>0}` instead of `Derivative[1,0][f][0,0]`.